# Mysql: Many to Many query based on Array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with 4 tables:

```
users             following                            
-------------     --------------------------------     
| id | etc.. |    | user_id (FK) | follow_id (FK) |    


articles          article_relations 
-------------     --------------------------------
| id | etc.. |    | user_id(FK) | article_id (FK) |
```

Users can follow other users so they can see what articles they saved.
So based on the current user id it needs to check which users he/she follows in the table "following". The users that are followed will be known now.

Based on those follower ids it needs to check in article_relations which article id's are linked in article_relations to the followers. Now it should now which articles are saved by which users.

So now in the table articles the article_ids needs to be queried keeping the information which user the article saved.

Is the database design logical?
It seems to me that querying the "stream" to see which articles the users you follow saved is very redundant.

Can someone tell me if the DB Design is OK and help me with the query to get the articles from
the users you follow including the user info?

I tried till my pants fell off and searched whole stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query, it'll get you user's information, and the people the current user is following's information and the articles that are saved by the people the current user is following.

```
SELECT u.*,
       fu.*,
       a.*
FROM following f
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = f.user_id
INNER JOIN users fu ON fu.id = f.follow_id
INNER JOIN article_relations ar ON ar.user_id = f.follow_id
INNER JOIN articles a ON a.id = ar.article_id
WHERE f.user_id = <currentUserId>
```

just change the `.*` to fields you need from each table.

Answer (score 0):

Structure looks fine to me. As for the query, try this. 
Join the following table (a) to the article_relations table (b)
by way of the follow_id then joining that to the article table (c) by article_id all based on the current user id.

I'm including the fictional fields article_name and article_field just as an example of what you might be pulling from the article table.

```
select  c.id,
        c.article_name,
        c.article_field

from    (following a 
        join article_relations b on a.follow_id = b.user_id)
        join articles c on b.article_id = c.id
where   a.user_id = current_user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can it be that this query wont return which user saved the article?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add the users table (d) into the mix for that.

```
select  c.id,
        c.article_name,
        c.article_field,
        d.id

from    ((following a 
        join article_relations b on a.follow_id = b.user_id)
        join articles c on b.article_id = c.id)
        join users d on a.user_id = d.id
where   a.user_id = current_user_id;
```